# xargs - place the argument in a different location in the command

Tags: xargs

Let's say I want to write a script that does `ls` with a prefix for each filename. I tried this

```
ls | xargs -n 1 echo prefix_
```

But the result was

```
prefix_ first_file
prefix_ second_file
...
```

How can I remove the space between the prefix and the filename? I.e. how to I make xargs put the variable after the command, without space? (Or in any other place for that matter)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The solution: `-I`

`-I` lets you name your argument and put it anywhere you like. E.g.

```
ls | xargs -n 1 -I {} echo prefix_{}
```

(replace `{}` with any string)

Comment: Note that the `-n 1` argument (max-args) is not needed in this example.